# Como obter dados deste Json?

Tags: android, json, listview

Preciso obter o name, a distance, photo e o id, que estão dentro de "data" e também preciso obter o route_id que está dentro de "ride".
Isso será preenchido num listview que contém estes primeiros dados. Ao clicar no btn_go, estes dados serão enviados a activity e também neste momento, o route_id deve ser enviado.

Json:

```
{
  "data": [
    {
      "id": 4,
      "start_address": "Aveninda Treze, Fortaleza - CE",
      "end_address": "Rua Delta, Fortaleza, Ceará 60713, Brazil",
      "start_lat": -3.7464,
      "start_lng": -38.5326,
      "end_lat": -3.79521,
      "end_lng": -38.5772,
      "user_id": 2,
      "distance": "6.521",
      "user": {
        "id": 2,
        "name": "User Test",
        "departure_time": "07:00:00",
        "arrival_time": "18:00:00",
        "address_lat": -3.7952,
        "address_lng": -38.577,
        "car": true,
        "photo_url": "https://test.com/img/avatar_female.png",
        "profile_mode": 2
      },
      "ride": {
        "id": 22,
        "schedule": "2017-03-22 18:00:00",
        "user_id": 2,
        "route_id": 4,
        "chat_id": 57,
        "channel": "chat.57",
        "disabled_reason": 0
      }
    }
```

Adapter:

```
 public class SearchAskPresenter extends BaseAdapter implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener, SubscriptionEventListener {


        private final SearchAskView searchaskview;
        CommunityRequestView viewR;
        private List<UserCommunity> usersList = new ArrayList<UserCommunity>();
        private List<SearchAskConstructor> usersSearchList = new ArrayList<SearchAskConstructor>();
        LayoutInflater inflater;
        TextView txt_Nome;
        TextView txt_Email;
        TextView txt_Distance;
        ImageButton btnGo;
        private UsersMySQLiteHelper serviceDB;
        private SessionManager sessionManager = new SessionManager();
        JsonObject json = new JsonObject();
        private ProgressDialog progress;
        SearchAskService service;

        public SearchAskPresenter(final SearchAskView view) {
            this.searchaskview = view;

            serviceDB = new UsersMySQLiteHelper(AppController.getAppContext());
            service = new SearchAskService(AppController.getAppContext());
            json = SharedPreferenceHelper.getScheduling(AppController.getAppContext());
    /*
            this.searchaskview.getListView().setAdapter(this);
            this.searchaskview.getListView().setOnItemClickListener(this);
    */  
//obtendo o retorno com o Json    
RequestManager.UsersSearchAskTest(json, new FutureCallback<String>() {
                @Override
                public void onCompleted(Exception e, String result) {
                    if (e==null || result!=null){
                        usersSearchList = new Gson().fromJson(new JsonParser().parse(result).getAsJsonObject().get("data").toString(), new TypeToken<ArrayList<SearchAskConstructor>>() {
                        }.getType()); //obtendo o Json

                        if (usersSearchList.size() > 0){
                            notifyDataSetChanged();
                        }
                    }else{
                        Toast.makeText(AppController.getAppContext(),"Não há sugestões",Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                }
            });
           // usersSearchList = serviceDB.getAllUsers(sessionManager.getLoggedUser().getCompany());
        }

        @Override
        public int getCount() {
            return usersSearchList.size();
        }

        @Override
        public Object getItem(int position) {
            return usersSearchList.get(position);
        }

        @Override
        public long getItemId(int position) {
            return position;
        }

        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            inflater = (LayoutInflater) searchaskview.getContext().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            //recupera o estado da posição atual
            final SearchAskConstructor searchUsers = usersSearchList.get(position); //TODO verificar onde pegar as informações de email--etc
            //Cria uma instancia do layout .. na view
            View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.searchask_item_list, null);
            //loadingStart(true,"Carregando...");
            txt_Email = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_email_searchask);
            txt_Nome = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_nome_searchask);
            txt_Distance = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txt_distance_searchask);
            btnGo = (ImageButton) view.findViewById(R.id.img_btn_searchask);

            txt_Email.setText(searchUsers.email);
            txt_Distance.setText(String.valueOf(searchUsers.distanceSearch));
            txt_Nome.setText(searchUsers.name);

            btnGo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
                @Override
                public void onClick(View v) {
                 /*   new Routes(searchaskview.getContext())
                            .open(URIs.Chat());*/

                    Intent intent = new Intent(AppController.getAppContext(), SearchAskFinishActivity.class);
                    searchaskview.getActivity().startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

            return view;
        }
```

Criei esta classe:

```
public class SearchAskConstructor {
    public int id;
    public String name;
    public String email;
    public String photo_url;
    public int route_id;
    public int user_id;

    public int profile_mode;
    public double distanceSearch;

    public SearchAskConstructor(String name, String photo_url, int profile_mode, int route_id, int user_id, double distance) {
        this.name = name;
        this.photo_url = photo_url;
        this.profile_mode = profile_mode;
        this.route_id = route_id;
        this.user_id = user_id;
        this.distanceSearch = distance;
    }


    public SearchAskConstructor() {
        super();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simples! Primeiro é necessário importar as seguintes `libs`, no qual é necessário trabalhar com as classes `JSONArray`, `JSONObject` e `JSONException`, para tratamento de exceções. Veja abaixo:

```
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;
```

Depois você pode criar um novo objeto com uma simples *string*, neste caso seu JSON. Vide comentários:

```
try {
    JSONObject myObject = new JSONObject(json);
    JSONArray myArrayData = myObject.getJSONArray("data");

    String distance = null, name = null;
    int id = 0, route_id = 0;

    for (int i = 0; i < myArrayData.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject another_json_object = myArrayData.getJSONObject(i);

        // resgata o id
        id = another_json_object.getInt("id");

        // resgata a distance
        distance = another_json_object.getString("distance");

        // resgata o nome dentro de user
        JSONObject obj = new JSONObject(another_json_object.getString("user"));
        name = obj.getString("name");

        // resgata route_id dentro de ride
        JSONObject obj2 = new JSONObject(another_json_object.getString("ride"));
        route_id = obj2.getInt("route_id");

    }
    // mostra na tela os valores resgatados
    Toast.makeText(this, 
         "name: " + name 
       + "\nid:" + id 
       + "\ndistance:" + distance 
       + "\nroute_id: " + route_id, 
            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

} catch (JSONException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Nesse caso, eu vou gerar uma carga grande no cliente(celuar) podem ser vários dados, o gson, tavez me permita fazer algo mais rapido, não? Ja que ele traz tudo isso, que vc fez sem a necessidade de um FOR.

Comment: Se me está confirmando isso, como não conseguiu fazer?! Qual seria a dúvida então? Você teria que detalhar melhor sua pergunta se caso queria usar alguma lib específica.